# Is there a way to not copy text by double clicking?

Tags: javascript, html

I dont want the text to get **marked** when i **double click** it.

Is there any way that this **can't** happen?

I didnt find **anything** about it, so i **couldn´t try** anything.

---

> The code is only for preventing copying while holding the left mouse button

`<body oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `user-select: none;` in your css:

```css
.unselectable {
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;  /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="unselectable">Cant highlight this</div>
```

You can also use it on a parent container (such as `body`) that will apply the rule to all the children, as long as the children do not modify `user-select`:

```css
.unselectable {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<body class="unselectable">
  <div>Cant highlight this</div>
  Or this
  <p>Or any of this</p>
</body>
```

Comment: @JackBashford What browser are you using?

Comment: The latest Safari.

Comment: @JackBashford try again now

Comment: @NicoEdlinger The tag will not matter here.

Answer (score 0):

User the `user-select` property - but make sure you add all the different browser/engine prefixes.

```css
.no-select {
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Webkit engine for Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-user-select: none;    /* Mozilla engine for Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;     /* Microsoft browsers */
  user-select: none;         /* Generic property usage */
}
```

```html
<p class="no-select">Unselectable</p>
```